# How to create a loop function with plotting function using dataframes

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, matrix, smoothing

So this is my code

```
require(splines)
library(ISLR)

 x <- runif(1000,min=0,max=10)
lambda=(2*x)+(0.2*x*sin(x))
y <- rpois(1000,lambda)

J <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

Now what I want to do, is smooth this function using

```
 smoothing=lm(y~ns(x=x,df=1),data=J)
```

and

```
ajust=predict(object=smoothing)
```

and then trace the smoothing line using

```
plot(x=x,y=y,cex=0.4)
lines(x,ajust,lwd=2)
```

I want a loop that combines those 3 operations , for df = 1,...,20 
so basically I want to trace 20 different smoothing lines (df=1,...,20)

I've used this and I think it works, but was wondering if I could keep everything in dataframe instead of doing the matrix thing.

```
dat=matrix(data=(1:20000),ncol=20)
for (i in (1:1000)){ 
for (d in (1:20)){
smoothing=lm(y~ns(x=x,df=d),data=J)
ajust[i,d]= predict(object=smoothing)[i] }}

trace= function(d){
plot(x,y)
lines(x,ajust[,d]) }

for (d in (1:20)) {trace(d)}
```

Any help is appreciated ! Thanks !!

Comment: do you want 20 different plots or 20 different lines?

Comment: welcome to SO. `Error in ns(x = x, df = 1) : could not find function "ns"`

Comment: @Tjebo he used `splines::ns()`. I don't think it matters tho, the question here is really "can I use a data.frame" and the answer is, of course, yes.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was my R. In this case the OP might want to specify the required packages

Comment: @akash87 20 different lines

Comment: @Tjebo Yes, you're correct, technically he is *required* to include the library() statements

Comment: @Tjebo I added the required packages ! Sorry

Comment: If this is more about plotting multiple modelled curves, I would suggest having a look at [tag:ggplot2] and geom_smooth , which would obviously in a first step require putting your data in a long format, and then you can simply separate by group

Comment: @Tjebo Actually I'm having a harder time coding the loop function..

Comment: ... which you may not necessarily need with the ggplot approach ...

Answer (score 1):

> I've used this and I think it works, but was wondering if I could keep
>   everything in dataframe instead of doing the matrix thing.

Yes, you can.

There were also a couple of small indexing problems and the `plot()` was not called in the right part in your code, fixed below:

```
# data.frame works fine:
ajust = structure(list(X1 = 1:1000, X2 = 1001:2000, X3 = 2001:3000, X4 = 3001:4000, 
                     X5 = 4001:5000, X6 = 5001:6000, X7 = 6001:7000, X8 = 7001:8000, 
                     X9 = 8001:9000, X10 = 9001:10000, X11 = 10001:11000, X12 = 11001:12000, 
                     X13 = 12001:13000, X14 = 13001:14000, X15 = 14001:15000, 
                     X16 = 15001:16000, X17 = 16001:17000, X18 = 17001:18000, 
                     X19 = 18001:19000, X20 = 19001:20000), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                -1000L))


smoothing=lm(y~ns(x=x,df=1),data=J)

for (i in (1:1000)){ 
  for (d in (1:20)){
    smoothing=lm(y~ns(x=x,df=d),data=J)
    ajust[i,d]= predict(object=smoothing)[i] }}

plot(x,y) # call this outside of the function/loop
trace= function(d){
  lines(x,ajust[,d]) }

for (d in (1:20)) {trace(d)}
```

Comment: @Tjebo Because you didn't load the packages he used.  It's from the package `splines`.

Comment: @Hack-R Sorry I edited my code, it was originally in french so i renamed my variables for better understanding

Comment: @AmarGhaly Thanks, I've updated my answer accordingly. Please let me know if this answers the question or if anything is missing. There were some other errors in your loop that I corrected.